# jQuery while loop to generate list

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to get a list from 1-100 without typing in each line.  I know it is a while loop but I've never had to use a while loop...thanks.

```
  <ul>
    <li>9.99</li>
    ...
    <li>9.01</li>
  </ul>
```

I kick myself in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $ul = $( '<ul>' );

for ( var i = 999; i > 900; i-- ) {
    $ul.append( '<li>' + ( i / 100 ).toFixed(2) + '</li>' );
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2YpxG/2/

Comment: great...just had to escape the </td>

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul></ul><script> 
var $ul = $("ul");
for(i = 99; i >= 1;i--){ 
  o = ''; 
  if (i < 10)  
       o = 0 ; 
  $ul.append('<li>9.'+o+i+'</li>'); 
}</script>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b0514

Comment: Cache the reference to the UL element in a variable. Doing selector searches (like `$('ul')`) inside loops can crash the web-site.

Comment: @imeVidas: not the website, as javascript is client-side

Comment: @imeVidas: ahh. it's ok. edited, and you're right and correct. It's unwanted load to user's browser

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a for loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/SgNDR/

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ul = $('ul');
for(i=1;i<1000;i++){
    $('<li/>').html((i/100).toFixed(2)).prependTo(_ul);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/XPrmm/

Comment: The problem with this is that you access the DOM in each iteration of the loop. DOM manipulation inside loops is best avoided (if possible) because it's an unnecessary burden for the JS engine. If the UL element is already present in the DOM, you could (1) detach it temporarily or (2) place the LI's inside a temporary UL and then transfer them to the actual UL (all at once) after the loop.

Comment: I have to correct myself, it's not a burden for the JS engine, but the web-page will reflow after each DOM manipulation, so it's an unnecessary burden for the layout engine.

Comment: Ya I'm aware, just written in haste ;)

Comment: No it's a burden on the selector engine too, no need to correct yourself.